# CSS descendant selectors

Tags: html, css

Can I use a combination of ID and elements to apply a style to a particular element?

for example:

```
<ul id="a">
  <li>
    <a href=...>Howdy</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href=...>Doody</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Is there a way to apply the style="font-size:small" to all the anchors that follow the UL with the ID of 'a'?

I'd think something like #a a {font-size:small} would work, but it's having no effect in the css file.

Thanks,

Jo

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use the structure of the HTML to select the anchor tags:

```
ul li a {
   font-size:small
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `ID` use `class` selector, so that same class name can be used to multiple `ul` elemements:

```css
.a li a {  /* you can also use .a a {....} */
  font-size: 40px;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="a">
  <li>
    <a href=...>Howdy</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href=...>Doody</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<ul class="a">
  <li>
    <a href=...>Hello</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href=...>Boy</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```